# Refresh a div or a table using javascript location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

it is possible to reload a div or a table using `location.reload();`?

after my ajax request i want to reload only the table portion and not the whole page since i'm styling most using kendo ui and css3 when it reloads it disrupts the UI which i don't want to happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a solution would be to extract that table/div in another page (jsp/html/php etc.) And in your main page that handles the ajax request you should include the newly created page using the html iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="my_page.html"></iframe>
```

Now in javascript you cand reload only the iframe which would refresh your table.

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Also you could read a bit more about this in the tutorial from the link bellow:

> http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Working-with-IFRAME-in-JavaScript/1/

Hope it helps.